# Transform laravel collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-collection

I need a certain array format like this:

```
    $data = [
        1 => ['order' => 3],
        2 => ['order' => 2],
        3 => ['order' => 1]
    ];
```

So when I do:

```
    $ids = $items->transform(function ($item) {
        return [$item->id => ['order' => rand(1,10)]];
    })->all();
```

Gives:

```
array:3 [
  0 => array:1 [
    1 => array:1 [
      "order" => 8
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:1 [
    2 => array:1 [
      "order" => 3
    ]
  ]
  2 => array:1 [
    3 => array:1 [
      "order" => 10
    ]
  ]
]
```

How can I transform the array in a specific way I need above? TIA

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use mapWithKeys, docs is here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-mapwithkeys

```
$keyed = $items->mapWithKeys(function ($item) {
    return [$item->id => ['order' => rand(1,10)]];
});

$ids = $keyed->all();
```